# SharePoint Online Access Request Status Codes

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom, sharepoint-online

I am using CSOM to retrieve items from the "Access Requests" list.

(https://sharepointSite.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Access%20Requests/pendingreq.aspx)

I am trying to figure out all the possible values of the "Status" field.

I have found the following values (just from looking at the access requests page and comparing to the data retrieved from my code)

- 0 = Pending
- 2 = Accepted
- 5 = Withdrawn

I have been unable to find any reference to these codes online.
Can anyone point me to a reference for these values or let me know what you figured our on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK whilst "_ModerationStatus" values are 0..4 (where 0=Approved), this is not the same as the "Status" field of an Access Request, which has values I have obtained from the Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAccessRequestsUtility (public enum StatusToInt), as well as accessrequestsviewtemplate.debug.js file (located in 15 hive, Layouts folder):

- 0=Pending (which could also trigger expired is an invitation)
- 1=Approved
- 2=Accepted
- 3=Denied
- 4=Expired
- 5=Revoked

I obtained this from powershell hitting the field and obtaining the SchemaXml property, reverse-engineering code as well as this MS link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj675013(v=office.12).aspx
Also look at these links depending upon your need: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spaccessrequests.changerequeststatus.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj674880(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Statuses are stored in `Approval Status` field (`Internal Name: _ModerationStatus`) for the specified `Access Requests` list

How to retrieve values of `_ModerationStatus` field via CSOM

```
var listTitle = "Access Requests";
var fieldName = "_ModerationStatus";
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var field = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldName);
ctx.Load(field);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var fieldChoice = ctx.CastTo<FieldChoice>(field);
var values = fieldChoice.Choices;
foreach (var value in values)
{
     Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

**About Moderation Status field**

According to [2.2.1.2.13 Moderation Status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh644558(v=office.12).aspx) the following are all possible valid values for Moderation Status:

> - 0 - The list item is approved.
> - 1 - The list item has been denied approval.
> - 2 - The list item is pending approval.
> - 3 - The list item is in the draft or checked out state.
> - 4 - The list item is scheduled for automatic approval at a future    date.